# Parsing Space Delimited Numbers from Getline

Tags: c++, parsing, getline

I am writing a small program that will read a plain ASCII text file containing 3 lines in 5 records, as follows:

> f_name l_name
>   ID#
>   int int int int

I successfully put the first 2 lines in the 1D arrays where they belong, but I am having trouble putting the series of ints in the 2D array. My closest approach to the solution has been using the line:

```
studentScores[row][col] = atoi(input.c_str());
```

However, atoi parses only the first number, then throws away the rest of the line. I need to put each number in the string in a separate element of the array. I tried using stringstream, but I cannot get it to work correctly; apparently, the function I want to use is included in a different version of stringstream than I am using.

What could I use to parse this string?

Comment: sscanf would read a C string, and extract 4 space delimited integers.

Comment: @gbulmer : Presumably this is for homework or a learning exercise -- if so, I don't think recommending C APIs to someone learning C++ is a great idea.

Comment: Yes, this is for a programming assignment that is due in about another 3 hours. I've been working on it all week.

Comment: @Opcode : In the future, please tag homework assignments as `homework`. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn - The OP used atoi, and atoi and sscanf are both available in C++, e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/ avoiding their use when one is stuck is IMHO the worse than "not a great idea" :-)

Comment: @gbulmer : I would wholeheartedly discourage the OP from using `atoi` as well.

Comment: @ildjarn - I believe their are multiple approaches to finding good solutions. I have spent years working with people who are facing deadlines (in education and commercially). In my experience, there is often a lot more than one error or obstacle to be overcome. Until their is a working solution, it is usually hard to understand how many obstacles their are yet to be discovered. IMHO, for some people, making progress, accepting that it is sub-optimal, is often more valuable than making optimal choices at every step. They get to a solution, and then improve it, with less stress and worry.

Comment: For a first approximation (on which hangs my grade), I'm happy to get whatever code works within my time constraints. I already had atoi coded, but had never seen sscanf. Implementing sscanf would have delayed me in trying to figure out how to fit it in the code; the same is true of replacing atoi with whatever ildjarn might suggest in its place. Over the last week, I've tried a half-dozen methods of accessing the file. I just need one that works within my constraints.

Comment: @ildjarn I added the homework tag. Thanks, again, for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// ...

int ints[4];
std::string input;
std::getline(stream, input);
std::istringstream(input) >> ints[0] >> ints[1] >> ints[2] >> ints[3];
```

(Error handling omitted for brevity.)

Comment: Will this code work with the other data types in the file? I do one getline at the start, then feed each string to the appropriate array (string[], int[], scores[][]).

Comment: @Opcode : Yes, it will work for any primitive type as well as `std::string` (though it will only give you one word at a time in this case; if you want more than that, use `std::getline` with the appropriate delimiter instead of `>>`).

Comment: FWIW, I just finished coding my program and getting it to work correctly. I still have 1.75 hours before I have to hand it in!